# Post comments into a specific status

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

As the title says, I'm trying to post a comment into a specific user status. So far, I can post comments and save them into firebase but those comments are displayed in all the statuses and of course it's because they are not referenced to that specific user status.

How can I achieve that?

Someone told me that each comment should have a property with the ID of the status or user to be able to make the query. But that's that I dont know how to do.

This is my firebase structure:

Firebase:

```
-users
-- 444198db-1052-4d8d-a1cd-c7e613fbe7c9
--- Status
--- StatusDate

-comments
-- K-nRDUXT07BllsO7T99
--- comment
--- commentDate
```

Here is my code to save the comments into the comments node in firebase:

```
$scope.addComment = function(){ 

                        console.log("Adding Comment");
                        var comment = $scope.comment;
                        console.log(comment);

                        var refcomment = new Firebase("https://firebaseurl/comments/");
                        refcomment.push({
                            comment: comment,
                            commentDate: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
                        });      

        }
```

And here the code to show the comments (ng-repeat):

```
refcomments = new Firebase("https://firebaseurl/comments/");
    $scope.comments = $firebaseArray(refcomments);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ComentariosCtrl">
  <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment Here..." ng-model="comment">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="addComment()">Post!</button>
  </span>
  </div><!-- /input-group -->
  <div class="cmt">
  <div class="panel" ng-repeat="comentarios in comments">
  <hr >
  <p>{{comentarios.comment}}</p>
  </div>
  </div><!--FIN DE COMENTARIOS -->
  </div>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Firebase doesn't have 'comments' or 'user status' in the API so is this a Firebase question or a coding question? If it's a coding question *with* Firebase, we need more information to assist: What are you trying to accomplish (e.g. Do you have a Users node and you are attempting to store comments within that node?) Do you have (brief) example code with a data structure? The initial question is vague so please update with more info.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for answering, yes this is a coding question related to Angularjs, Firebase. What I am trying to do is to be able to comment on each user status and save that comment into firebase referenced to that user status (sorry if its not so clear). I updated with some code and my firebase nodes to let you know, as you can see, I can create the comment and save it into firebase but dont know how to reference it into that user status and not the others, because when I do the ng-repeat, the comments are displayed into all the users statuses and not the one I commented.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what 'posting a comment into a specific user status' means exactly but here are a couple of thoughts (and I hope I'm on the right track)

In your example, there's no way to 'relate' the user to the comment. There's about 100 different ways to do it but one flattened structure that could be easily queried for a users comments is:

```
users
  user_id_0001
    user_name: "Bill"
    user_status: "some status"
    status_date: "some status_date"
  user_id_0002
    user_name: "Ted"
    user_status: "some status"
    status_date: "some status_date"

comments
  comment_id_0001
    made_by_user_id: "user_id_0001"
    comment: "Hey Ted!"
  comment_id_0002
    made_by_user_id: "user_id_002"
    comment: "Hey Bill! Let's go on a most excellent adventure"
```

The comments node could then be queried for made_by_user_id = "user_id_0001" which would retrieve all of Bill's comments. Remember in Firebase the flatter the better. Excellent!

Another, less flexible option is to store a users comments within their own users node

```
users
      user_id_0002
        user_name: "Ted"
        user_status: "some status"
        status_date: "some status_date"
        comments
          comment_id_0001:
            comment: "Just call me Neo"
            timestamp: "some timestamp"
          comment_id_0002:
            comment: "I feel like I'm in the Matrix"
            timestamp: "some timestamp"
          comment_id_0003:
            comment: "You trying to tell me.. that I can dodge bullets?"
            timestamp: "some timestamp"
```

Now if you want to retrive all of a users comments, they are just within their own users node at  /users/user_id_0002/comments

It really depends on your usage of the data.

The key is to disassociate your data from the node name it's stored in. Using the push() function will generate a unique id can help do that - in the examples above user_id_0001 an comment_id_0001 are generated in this way.

Comment: Thanks for taking time and answer. Sorry for the unclear description, Im gonna try to explain you better. What Im trying to do is similar to the comment system of facebook or any other comment system. You can comment to a post of someone else, so that comment is saved and reference it only to that post and not the others. As someone else told me, the comments must have the ID of the post but thats what I dont know how to achieve, because it has to be automatic. **Now Im thinking...what about using lenght??**